# Convert c# Class to XML with double datatype

Tags: c#, xml, netsuite

I am trying to convert Netsuite Record(CashSale) into XML equivalent using XMLSerializer in c# application. However properties with datatype double not reflected in XML string

I have created a class in c# with double datatype property , I can see the property and value in xml string

I have tried converting Netsuite Cashsale class to xml string. Double datatype properties are not reflected in the xml string

```
CashSale cs = new CashSale();
            cs.altHandlingCost = Convert.ToDouble(10.73.ToString(), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            cs.entity = new RecordRef { internalId = "311", type = RecordType.customer };
            cs.externalId = "54658";
            cs.memo = "POS Memo";
            cs.tranDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
            cs.undepFunds = false;
            cs.account = new RecordRef { internalId = "915" };
            cs.subsidiary = new RecordRef { internalId = "2" };
            cs.location = new RecordRef { internalId = "101" };
            CashSaleItem[] item = { new CashSaleItem { amount = 10,taxAmount=1, taxCode = new RecordRef { internalId = "7" },  description = "dec", item = new RecordRef { externalId = "4000Bev" } } };

            cs.itemList = new CashSaleItemList { item = item };

            var a=Serialize(cs);
            WriteResponse writeRes = Client.Service.upsert(cs);
public static string Serialize(object dataToSerialize)
    {
        if (dataToSerialize == null) return null;

        using (StringWriter stringwriter = new System.IO.StringWriter())
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(dataToSerialize.GetType());
            serializer.Serialize(stringwriter, dataToSerialize);
            return stringwriter.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Expected: For Netsuite class, all properties including double datatype should be converted into XML string
Actual: Properties with datatype Double are not converted into XML

Minimum Reprocable Steps:

1. Create a Web Reference using https://webservices.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2019_1_0/netsuite.wsdl
2. Create a object for CashSale
3. Assign some values for double datatype fields alongwith others.
4. Serialise to XML string

Comment: what is the outcome currently? An Exception? Are they missing?
What attributes does that object have besides those (`XXXSpecified` allows to say wether or not some attribute should be serialized or not; Maybe some `XmlXXX` attributes are already attached in there)?

Comment: There is no exception. But property with double datatype(amount,taxamount) are missing from the xml string

Comment: It looks like you can do this with your own class with double properties; it's just when you use a Netsuite class that the problem arises? I expect they've marked the properties on their class as non-serializable. Sounds like a question for Netsuite.

Comment: Hi Henry, Yes the problem is specific to the Netsuite Class. Is it possible to serialize these properties in c# ?

Comment: Make sure the properties are public.  Only public objects get serialized.

Comment: @Mayank Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. Also include the XML currently generated and the XML you want to generate instead.

Comment: @Progman I have added steps for minimal reproducible example in my question

Comment: @jdweng Yes the property is public

Answer (score 0):

**This may help you out:**

```
public string ToXML()
    {
        using(var stringwriter = new System.IO.StringWriter())
        { 
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());
            serializer.Serialize(stringwriter, this);
            return stringwriter.ToString();
        }
    }

 public static YourClass LoadFromXMLString(string xmlText)
    {
        using(var stringReader = new System.IO.StringReader(xmlText))
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(YourClass ));
            return serializer.Deserialize(stringReader) as YourClass ;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution for this issue:

Changes Done: I have added one more boolean field **amountspecified** in request and set it to **true**